# How to count total distance covered in GMSMutablePath iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I have one full route which walked by user and its Coordinate points.

> i have create path of it.

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latNew, longitude: longNew))
```

//Adding here multiple locations.

> Showing path to map.

```
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0;
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
let styles = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.black), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.clear)]
let lengths = [2, 2];
polyline.spans = GMSStyleSpans(polyline.path!, styles, lengths as [NSNumber], kGMSLengthRhumb)
polyline.geodesic = true
polyline.map = self.viewGMap
```

Now i wants to calculate total distance covered in this route only.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find length like this:

```
// Geodesic length, in meters, along Projected segments
NSLog(@"Lenght Length Projected=%f",[path lengthOfKind:kGMSLengthProjected]);

// Rhumb length, in meters, along rhumb (straight line) segments
NSLog(@"Lenght Length Rhumb=%f",[path lengthOfKind:kGMSLengthRhumb]);

// Length in projected space, along Geodesic segments.
NSLog(@"Lenght Length Geodesic=%f",[path lengthOfKind:kGMSLengthGeodesic]);
```